# C++/CLI HttpWebRequest::GetRequestStream() fails after first time

Tags: c++, httpwebrequest, response, dispose, command-line-interface

I had to use C++/CLI in one of my programs, but I have never used it before. So it gave me a few problems. This is basically an function which send an http request to a login page. It work for the first user I try to, but with the second user, it fails on the GetRequestStream(). I googled about this, and most topics were about deleting/dispose it. I believe im doing that right now? Still I have to wait like 20 seconds before a timeouts come (Time-out excpetion). I have no ideas anymore how I can fix this.

```
bool GetAuthKey(std::string _username, std::string _pass, std::string& _key)
{
System::String ^ username = gcnew String(_username.c_str());
System::String ^ pass = gcnew String(_pass.c_str());

System::Net::CookieContainer ^cookieContainer = gcnew System::Net::CookieContainer();

System::Net::HttpWebRequest ^first_request = safe_cast<System::Net::HttpWebRequest^>(System::Net::HttpWebRequest::Create("https://passport.nexoneu.com/login/"));
first_request->CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
first_request->Method = "GET";
first_request->KeepAlive = true;
first_request->GetResponse();

System::Net::Cookie ^theme = gcnew System::Net::Cookie("theme", "NexonEU");
theme->Domain = ".nexoneu.com";
cookieContainer->Add(theme);

/*ArrayWriter ^postData = gcnew ArrayWriter();
postData.WriteBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"account\":{\"userId\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\""));
postData.WriteBytes(pass);// changed
postData.WriteBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\",\"accessedGame\":\"NexonEU\",\"captcha\":null,\"isSaveID\":true}}"));*/

String ^data = "{\"account\":{\"userId\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + pass + "\",\"accessedGame\":\"NexonEU\",\"captcha\":null,\"isSaveID\":true}}";
array<Byte> ^buffer = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(data);

System::Net::HttpWebRequest ^request = safe_cast<System::Net::HttpWebRequest^>(System::Net::HttpWebRequest::Create("https://passport.nexoneu.com/Service/Authentication.asmx/Login"));
request->Method = "POST";
request->CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
request->Date = DateTime::UtcNow;
request->ServicePoint->Expect100Continue = false;// think ive to change this

request->Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
request->KeepAlive = true;
request->ContentLength = buffer->Length;
request->ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
request->Host = "passport.nexoneu.com";
request->Referer = "https://passport.nexoneu.com/login/";
request->UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36";

request->Headers->Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
request->Headers->Add("Accept-Language", "en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
request->Headers->Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
request->Headers->Add("DNT", "1");
request->Headers->Add("Origin", "https://" + request->Host);


System::IO::Stream ^stream = request->GetRequestStream(); // this crashes
stream->Write(buffer, 0, buffer->Length);

stream->Flush();
stream->Close();
delete stream;

System::Net::HttpWebResponse ^response = safe_cast<System::Net::HttpWebResponse^>(request->GetResponse());

for each(System::Net::Cookie ^cookie in response->Cookies)
{
    if (cookie->Name->ToUpper()->Equals("NPP"))
    {
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;

        _key = context.marshal_as<std::string>(cookie->Value);
        break;
    }
}

request->Abort();
response->Close();

delete request;
delete response;

return !_key.empty();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:`delete stream;`

In C++/CLI, delete calls the Dispose method on a managed object if it implements the System::IDisposable interface, and Stream does implements it.

But the code already called close() function on that stream, the [close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function  also calls the Dispose method. So the code called Dispose() twice on that stream, I think this is the reason for your error.